# c++ reduce library size by excluding unnecessary functions programmatically?

Tags: c++, optimization, libraries, minimize

What is the easier way to reduce library size by selecting only needed functions and eliminating unnecessary files ?
Is there a script to accomplish this task for c++ libraries?

Comment: Linkers typically try to automatically detect which functions, or at least files, are reachable and drop the unwanted ones. Check your manual to see how to set this up. Beware that it's still easy for things to be dragged in unnecessarily and if size is a concern then you should be taking occasional glances at your map file to see what is actually going on. Tables of functions pointers/factories and the like are frequent culprits, and take care in precisely what you are exporting from dynamically linked libraries.

Comment: **Why** do you ask? What are the circumstances for wanting to reduce library size? Usually it does not matter, because libraries are shared! Please **edit your question** to improve it, give your motivations, the context, what compiler, operating system, optimization flags are you using, what is the actual library, etc...

Comment: Why? Linkers don't link anything from a library that isn't reachable. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I am linking against grt : https://github.com/nickgillian/grt (Gesture Recognition Toolkit) which is a organized like a collection of modules for preprocessing, feature extraction, clustering, classification, regression and post processing of data .

Comment: Stripping off unwanted modules looks more like a human job .. I am trying to simplify code porting to multiple platforms to avoid troubles .

Comment: 'Stripping off unwanted modules' is the *linker's* job. Do you have some evidence that it isn't doing it? A linker will process every object file you present to it, and search for missing references in the libraries. It won't link in entire libraries. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's a matter of mental order I guess ..

Answer (score 3):

You probably should first try to set up your compilation to minimize size. And the answer to your question depends a lot on the compiler, the linker, what operating system, the optimization flags, etc...

With a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler (`g++`) on Linux, you should try to compile *and link* wih optimization for size (`-Os`) and [link time optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interprocedural_optimization) (`-flto`).

So put

```
CXX=g++ -flto -Os
```

near the beginning of your `Makefile` or simply run `make CXX='g++ -flto -Os'` after a `make clean`

BTW, [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) also knows about `-flto` (and uses [GOLD](http://llvm.org/docs/GoldPlugin.html) like GCC does)

Notice that a shared [library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29) (or probably a DLL in Microsoft world) needs to contain all the code (precisely because it is shared between several processes and programs). You might link your library statically (then use `g++ -flto -Os`  both when building the static library and when linking it to the main program)

Very often, having shared libraries is more worthwhile than trying to reduce their space.

If on Linux, read the [program library howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO).

Comment: didn't know about -flto option, I'll try to issue a feature request to `Cmake` developers to support it.

Comment: There is already support in `cmake`  for LTO. You could simply try `make clean` then `make CXX='g++ -flto -Os'`

Comment: This require manual intervention for GCC, I mean CMake already use automatically certain compiler flags (for example for GCC in Release build use `-O3`) do you actually claim that `-flto` is automatically used with some build configuration without the user specify manually a flag? (having that automatic would be great because you get a free optimization without actually having to maintain a separate flag for GCC wich is great when you compile a library with many dependencies against 3 different compilers and 10 compiler versions). Manually specifing flags is a well known cmake antipattern

Comment: But you should read cmake documentation. It does know about LTO.

Comment: Ok assume Cmake know about LTO, how do you enable that without providing manually flags that are specific to GCC? A text search over generated makefiles (all build configurations tried) and over documentation shows no match for `lto` or `link time optimization`.. I'm interested in having that enabled for GCC of course.

Comment: I don't know much about `cmake` (and I don't like it). Notice that `-flto` is not specific to GCC, [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) knows it too.

Comment: I hated cmake for years because I was not able to use it to build anything with it (not even Ogre3D), the reason was simply people didn't use cmake correctly and provided horrible scripts, now I use cmake reguarly and actively patch cmake scripts for lots of opensource projects.. Clang try  to be compatible with GCC so it has mostly same flags, but MSVC does not (and I target that too).

Answer (score 2):

In typical C++ applications, templates stand for a large portion of the functionality (e.g. STL `vector`, `string`, etc). These functions are ONLY generated as code when they are used (although they MAY be generated as inline functions, which in SOME cases can lead to large code).

The linker will only "pick" code that is needed for your application (including of course, functions called by functions that you use). However, the base runtime on for example Linux is quite large, because it calls a lot of functionality that in turn uses a fair bit of other function - so your basic executable size is quite large. Adding more of your own code will not increase the size by a significant amount in the typical case.

If size is critical, then using a "small C++ library" would perhaps be a choice - there are different such libraries available for different OSes. Using options such as `-Os` for the compiler to tell it to "make the code small" (in other words, don't inline functions unless the code is shorter by inlining than by calling the function, and don't unroll loops, etc, etc - but DO inline functions called only once, as that does make the code shorter)

Comment: why everyone assume he is using GCC he don't even mentioned the compiler. As far as we know he could be using visual studio wich generates by default few MB static libraries even for few lines of code unless you play with compiler options

Comment: I made no such assumption. gcc, clang or visual studio's linker works almost identical, and all have a "optimise for small size", using `-Os` (as does armcc). Even the Atari ST compiler/linker I used 30 years ago was able to only include the functions that are actually used, so I doubt any other compiler produced since DOESN'T...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do a library heavy refactoring (assuming you have access to sourcecode wich is not always a realistic hypotesis), is to link it as static library, or compile as part of your application: all compilers will benefit from that.

Note that Clang has a exceptional behaviour in the sense it is able to do a lot of optimizations at static linking time compared to other compilers.

If you instead have to use a DLL for some reason, you can try to tweak visibility of exported symbols (you can hide symbols not visible in client code and export only symbols you use): note that this may enable some optimization regardin speed and binary size but could be a tedious work (I would count it as a major refactoring because has the potential to break things).

If you are using dependency injection containers you can probably instrument them to warn about unused dependencies so that you can easily wire them out without ever the need of touching source code (you do some refactoring of the container but not of your whole codebase) except source code in composition root.

Comment: GCC is also able to do LTO.

Comment: Yes but in a different way:
GCC:
https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization
Clang:
http://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html
It does not dump some internal state (wich may actually be more an implementation detail than something relevant) i'm not saying GCC does no optimization (and actually still prefer GCC)

Answer (score 0):

1, using lto

2, using version script to control which symbols are exported

3, use

```
CFLAGS="-Os -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
        -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -flto"
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-s -Wl,-Bsymbolic -Wl,--gc-sections"
```

4, strip library

5, use -Oz with clang or -Os with gcc compiler.